# How to burn captions with quality similar to VLC using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to burn a caption on a video using `fluent-ffmpeg` but, am getting blurry captions after burning.

I have tried many combinations of settings but neither would produce good quality like VLC.

These are the settings I used:

```
function processVideo(localTempPath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ffmpeg()
      .input("xx.mp4")
      .videoFilter([
        {
          filter: 'subtitles',
          options: "gaza_edit.ass",
          expression: 'subtitles'
        },
        'scale=-1:360'
      ])
      // .inputOptions('-scodec mov_text')
      .withVideoCodec("libx264")
      .withAudioCodec("copy")
      .withOutputFormat("mp4")
      /**
       * ou control the tradeoff between video encoding speed and compression efficiency with the -preset options. 
       * Those are ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium, slow, slower, veryslow. Default is medium. 
       * The veryslow option offers the best compression efficiency (resulting in a smaller file size for the same quality) but it is very slow – as the name says.
       */
      .outputOptions("-preset veryfast")
      .outputOptions('-max_muxing_queue_size 1024') // Add max_muxing_queue_size option for output
      // .outputOptions("-s 1280x720")
      // .outputOptions("-sws_flags lanczos")
      // .outputOptions(['-x264-params crf=18'])
      .output("output.mp4")
      .on("error", (error) => reject("Failed to process video: " + error))
      .on("progress", (progress) => console.log(progress))
      .on('end', function () {
        console.log('Finished processing');
      })
      .run();
  });;
}
```

**1**
is blurry

**2**
is more sharp and clear

[image]

Comment: Is the rest of the video similarly blurry? Are you playing the video at a native scale and resolution? What is the video resolution?

Comment: I beleive it's 720